# how do i make so a region of the screen/ a button will be able to move the player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, mobile

I want my game to support mobile devices but in order to do it I need to make the player movement compatible, but i don't know how to do it

how can I make a button/region of the screen trigger the right or left movement of the player?

here is my player movement script:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovment : MonoBehaviour
{
    // rb = Rigidbody
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public Joystick joystick;


    public float forwardForce = 2000f;
    public float sidewaysForce = 500f;

    // using it to mess with physics
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // add forward force
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey("d")) 
        {
            rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("right"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("left"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if (rb.position.y < -1f) 
        {
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add two UI buttons, one for left and one for right.

Comment: and what about the script to activate it then you click on one of the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

This code gets the first touch/finger on the screen, if you wanted to get multiple touches use Input.GetTouch(1) for the second finger on the screen, Input.GetTouch(2) for the third etc. From now on you use "touch" to reference the first touch/finger the user puts on the screen.

```
void Update()
    {
       if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            // touch.position gives you the position of the touch in screen space pixel coordinates.
            Vector2 touchPosition = touch.position;
        {
    {
```

I understand you also want to check if the touch is on the left or the right side of the screen so you can move your player left&right. Every phone/tablet has different screens and different screen bounds so you also need to get the screenbounds of the device. You can do that with the following code:

```
// This code gets the screen bounds of the device and stores it in a vector
screenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(Screen.width, Screen.height));
```

So if we wrap it all up you need to implement the following code into your game:

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            Vector2 touchPosition = touch.position;
            screenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(Screen.width, Screen.height));
            if (touchPosition.x > (screenBounds.x / 2)) 
            {
                // ADD THE MOVE RIGHT CODE HERE  
            }
            else 
            {
                // ADD THE MOVE LEFT CODE HERE
            } 
        {
    {
```

Comment: I have more questions because I'm still new to this.
the `// ADD THE MOVE RIGHT CODE HERE` means I need to add this? `rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);`

and where I have to put this script? in the main camera? or in the player?

Comment: i tried putting it in the same script as the player movement but it's not working